# Counting shared and unique markers across several groups

Tags: r

I have a set of markers typed in several populations. Some markers are shared across groups (could be all groups or less e.g. only 3 of the 5 groups shares a marker), whilst other markers are unique to a particular population. Some markers may be absent from some populations but present in others. I want to count the markers which are unique to each population.
I have 5 separate files listing the markers detected in each population, the input file is;

> Markers_Group_1
>   snp1
>   snp2
>   snp3
>   snp4
>   snp5
>   snp6
>   snp7
>   snp8
>   snp9
>   snp10
>   snp11...snp100

The input file for Group 2 may have snps 5,6,9, 20-70. Likewise for groups 3 to 5; i.e. they carry a different combination of snps. Therefore if all 5 files were merged into a single file there would be some cells that are empty.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Excel VLookup.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

That can give you something that looks like this.

```
ALL MARKERS      File1     File2    File3    File4    last_file_with_marker   COUNT
snp1              snp1      snp1     snp1     snp1           File4               4
snp2              snp2      snp2              snp2           File4               3
snp3              snp3      snp3     snp3                    File3               3
snp4                        snp4                             File2               1
snp5              snp5      snp5     snp5     snp5           File4               4
```

If File1 is on Sheet 2, your formula for all the cells in File1, File2, File3, File4 columns might look something like:
=VLOOKUP($A2&"",Sheet2!Data,1,FALSE)

Then you can add something in the next column (title: last_file_with_marker)
=LOOKUP(A2,B2:E2,$B$1:$E$1)

And a count column to find the ones with only one.
=COUNTIF(B2:E2, A2)

You can sort on your count column to find the ones with unique markers.

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for an advanced automated solution to use in the r software since I have ~500 snps typed in large groups (n=3000 individuals).